# Outlook changing border css on table

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, outlook-2013

I'm having problems with creating some HTML emails to display correctly in Outlook desktop 2013, I've managed to solved all my problems up until now about from this border issue that I just can't understand.

Basically in the outlook web app my table looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpTui.jpg

But on Outlook 2013 it somehow looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8jFp.jpg

Here's my table code before outlook eats it up and makes this mess:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="margin:auto;">
<thead>
    <tr height="40" style="background-color: #CFE1D3; ">
        <th align="center" width="17%" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></strong></th>
        <th align="center" width="17%" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Product Code') ?></strong></th>
        <th align="center" width="30%" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Product Description') ?></strong></th>
        <th align="center" width="10%" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px;"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Quantity') ?></strong></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td align="center" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px; border-right-width: 0; border-top-width: 0;"><img src="images/product"  alt="test" width="100%" height="auto" align="left" /></td>
     <td align="center" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px; border-right-width: 0; border-top-width: 0;">test</td>
     <td align="center" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px; border-right-width: 0; border-top-width: 0;">This is a test</td>
     <td align="center" style="line-height: 1.6em; border-style: solid; border-color: #777; border-width: 1px; border-top-width: 0;">1</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ this is a handy page for checking if a style can be used by some mail programms. As border-spacing is not allowed in outlook.

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl Yes it is a handy tool I've used it thus far. But I'm not using border spacing in my code?

Comment: Oops you're right, it's cellspacing xD Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4):

I came across this question quickly when searching for an answer, but none of the other answers worked for me.

In my case the answer was to use the following inline style on my `<table>`:

```
style="border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;"
```

Comment: This solved my issues with table border rendering. It seems Microsoft Outlook requires the use of these special attributes to render tables correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try using a 6 digit hexadecimal colour code instead on your `border-color`: `#777777`, 3 digit hex codes are not fully supported across various clients, and you will find that the color may change between them. (While if you use a 6 digit it will be consistent across everything so try and make that a habit).

[Litmus blog on this](https://litmus.com/blog/background-colors-html-email)

Your should also add `style="display:block";` within all of your image tags.

Comment: I also have a felling that cellpadding is also not very well supported, so it may be best to try setting that to zero too.

Answer (score 1):

Have yout tried adding `border-collapse: collapse` to the **table**'s style attribute?
Basically Outlook supposes that the borders of the table cells should not overlap, unless being told to.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of how the code addresses what Outlook is thinking.  +1